# i need to make an image in the canvas in tkinter heres the code but errors are coming

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

```
c = tkinter.Canvas(width=275,height=300)
so_ramdom = tkinter.PhotoImage("/Users/vikranthracherla/Downloads/download.jpeg")
c.create_image(image=so_ramdom)
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d27.py", line 33, in <module>
    c.create_image(image=so_ramdom)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2325, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2309, in _create
    cnf = args[-1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: c.create_image(x, y, .....  Also noticed you are not passing in any coordinates onto

Comment: Note that apart from the above issue, `tkinter.PhotoImage(file="...")` should be used instead and `tkinter.PhotoImage()` does not support JPEG image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add coordinates x and y

c.create_image(x, y, ..... Also noticed you are not passing in any coordinates onto.

Comment: I think this answer could be a bit more clear...

Comment: ok I tried but it is not working

Comment: what is a traceback

Comment: Did you enter value for x and y?

Comment: yes but did not come

Comment: Add lower character r to `r"/Users/vikranthracherla/Downloads/download.jpeg"`